# Use LotusScript or Rules to stop some emails in Lotus Notes from causing a new email alert

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I would like to setup Lotus Notes to move certain incoming emails to a particular folder and mark those emails as already read in such a way that I do *not* receive a new email alert from Lotus Notes. I am able to filter for the correct email (by subject line, etc) and have Lotus Notes move the incoming email to a folder and mark the message as already read but getting it to *not* give me a new email alert is the part I am having trouble with.

I do *not* want to disable email alerts for all incoming emails, just for some that meet certain criteria. I am open to solutions that use Lotus Notes Rules but I am thinking I will need to use LotusScript. I am using IBM Lotus Notes 8.5 on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the rules?

Comment: @umeli Yes, I have tried the rules. The rules are allowing me to move the email but there is no rule "action" for setting the email as having been read. If I use LotusScript to set the email as having been read (since I cannot do this with a rule) the email will be marked read but only *after* I receive an alert. Unfortunately, it is the alert that I am trying to avoid receiving in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done anything like that, but what I would try is to create a Lotusscript agent triggered to run "before mail is received". Then you can use the MarkRead method of the NotesDocument class.

Comment: I have now created an agent triggered to run "before mail is received" based on the code here [link](http://lotus-blogs.blogspot.com/2007/08/all-about-pre-deliverybefore-new-mail.html) . Unfortunately, the agent does not appear to ever run unless I right click and select Run or Test. When I send myself an email and then right click on the agent and select Log then Lotus Notes tells me that there is no log because the agent has never been run. Could this be server settings that do not allow me to run this type of agent? Another reason the agent might not be running at all? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, if I run this agent manually (via Run or Test) the session.DocumentContext object is set to Nothing which is preventing the code from working.